# Fixed effect or random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model

Currently, I am trying to evaluate the AB testing of my movie recommender systems and I want to see which option is better in terms of watch_duration (duration of the user watching a movie).

[image]

However, I am struggling with creating my model. At first, I wanted to create a fixed effects models but I do not have data on each user daily. As most users just watch once a week during the testing period (of a month) and I would have a problem with aggregating the data. I would like to account for title effects but that would require me to dummy the titles into 850 rows and I have an imbalance of the movies being watched (some are popular and watched often and some are barely ever watched) -- unless that is okay to do?

Therefore, I thought a possible solution would be using a mixed-effects model. Then I would not have to convert my dataset to panel data but basically can leave it as is and take titles into account as a random effect. I can do the same for user_id and date, avoiding my table in the end to have a thousand rows.

My question however is, should I be using a mixed effects model? Is this realistic and logical? I have seen mixed effects models being used for movie recommender systems but they did not take into account user-fixed effects or title-fixed effects. Is it a good idea to use user_id, title/content_id and date as random effects?

Here is my R code:

```
model_watchtime <- lmer(watched_duration ~ group + day_of_week + genres + imdb_rating + recommended_duration + (1|user_id) + (1|title) + (1|date), data = df_interaction)
```

Thoughts? Ideas?

TLDR: Is the fixed effects model or mixed effects model more suitable for me? Should I make user_id, title and date random effects? Or fixed effects?